# Multiply two values together from a single database column

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have some data as follows:

```
Name             Processors
dab1             8x10 - 1.06 GHz
bac3             2x6 - 2.4 GHz
abc1             4x8 - 2 GHz
cab2             2x4 - 1.2 GHz
```

From the 'Processors' column, I need to be able to multiply the first number and the second number together (ex: 8*10 = 80, 2*6 = 12, etc) to check a condition.

Example query:

```
SELECT * FROM HOST_TABLE WHERE COMPUTED_PROCESSOR_VALUE > 16
```

How can I calculate this value? There will always be an 'x' between the numbers but the numbers could be single or double digit.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need the results within the database (as input for other SQLs) or is it going to be shown on a GUI?

Comment: Yes, within the database. Optimally the calculation will be done in that sample query I gave above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dacc8/16/0)

```
SELECT m.Name, m.Processors FROM
(
  SELECT Name, Processors, SUBSTR(Processors, 1, INSTR(Processors, 'x', 1, 1)-1) AS FirstValue,
  SUBSTR(Processors, INSTR(Processors, 'x', 1, 1) + 1, INSTR(Processors, ' ', 1, 1) - INSTR(Processors, 'x', 1, 1)) AS SecondValue
  FROM MyTable
) m 
WHERE m.FirstValue * m.SecondValue > 16
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions, your query would look similar to this:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           processors, '^[:digit:]{1,2}')) * 
       TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           processors, '[:digit:]{1,2})', INSTR(processors, 'x'))) 
       AS computed_processor_value 
FROM host_table 
WHERE computed_processor_value > 16;
```

I can't test it right now, but it should get you started.

References for Oracle 10.1g (adjust for your version if necessary):

[REGEXP_SUBSTR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm)

[Multilingual Regular Expression Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/ap_posix001.htm)

Comment: regular expressions are the way to go!